# I want to wrap text only above and below a figure inside of a column

Tags: spacing, floats, multicol, wrapfig

So, I have created a two-column latex document using the `multicol` package. For the main body of the text, the code looks something like this:

```
\documentclass[11pt, A4]{article}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{multicol}

\begin{document}
   \begin{multicol*}{2}

   Some text...

   \begin{figure}[H]
     \centering
      \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{images/test.jpg}
      \captionof{figure}{Caption}
      \label{fig:my_label1}
   \end{figure}

   More text...

   \end{multicol}    
\end{document}
```

This produces the following result:
[image: non-wrapfigure]

Now, I want to have the text below the figure (Ut egestas mauris...) to wrap around the figure and fill the previous column as well. I tried using `wrapfigure` but that produces the following result:

```
\begin{wrapfigure}{r}{\linewidth}
   \centering
   \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{images/test.jpg}
   \captionof{figure}{Caption}
   \label{fig:my_label1}
\end{wrapfigure}
```

[image: wrapfigure]

This is close, but the figure should move to the next column while the text stays to fill the gap. Are there any options for `wrapfigure` that would do this, or any other package? I suppose the only thing it needs to do is have the text only wrap above and below the image, not beside it. However, I am not really familiar with how latex renders these things, so I do not know if it is even possible.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: Change `width=\linewidth` to `width=.5\linewidth`.

Comment: Alas, multicol doesn't support afterpage either. BTW, you MWE is still full of errors.

Comment: Often a wrapfigure is not a very good idea in one column document. In two column documents is directly a bad idea.

Answer (score 1):

This solution uses `\split` to insert a box into the middle of a paragraph at the start of the next column.  It works for both right and left columns.

Note, multicols sets `\pagegoal` to include all the columns together.

```
\documentclass[11pt, A4]{article}
%\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{lipsum}% MWE only

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\split}[2]% #1 = text, #2 = insert
{\par\bgroup
  \setbox0=\vbox{\strut #1\strut}% measure height
  \sbox1{#2}% ditto
  \dimen0=\dimexpr \pagegoal-\pagetotal-\col@number\baselineskip\relax% fudge factor
  \dimen1=\pagegoal% compute height of one column
  \ifnum\col@number>1\relax
    \divide\dimen1 by \col@number
  \fi
  \advance\dimen1 by -\baselineskip% fudge factor
  \loop\ifdim\dimen0>\dimen1% space left in this column
    \advance\dimen0 by -\dimen1
  \repeat
  \dimen1=\dimexpr \ht1+\dp1+\textfloatsep\relax% space needed for insert
  \ifdim\dimen1>\dimen0
    \ifdim\ht0>\dimen0
      \setbox2=\vsplit0 to \dimen0
      \unvbox2
      \noindent\box1
      \vskip\textfloatsep
      \unvbox0
    \else% entire text will fit into column
      \unvbox0
      \vskip\textfloatsep% probably ignored
      \noindent\box1
      \vskip\textfloatsep
    \fi
  \else% insert will fit into column
    \vskip\intextsep
    \noindent\box1
    \vskip\intextsep
    \unvbox0
  \fi
\egroup\par}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
   \begin{multicols}{2}

   \lipsum[1]
   %\lipsum[2-4]% to test second column

   \split{\lipsum[2]}{\begin{minipage}{\columnwidth}
      \centering
      \includegraphics[width=\linewidth, height=0.5\textheight]{example-image}
      \captionof{figure}{Caption}
      \label{fig:my_label1}
   \end{minipage}}

   \lipsum[3-6]

   \end{multicols}    
\end{document}
```