# Reduce white space before figure in multicols environment

Tags: floats, multicol

I need to write a paper with two columns so I am using `\begin{multicols}{2}`. However, I had a problem while putting figures in this report. So I searched and I found this :

```
\newenvironment{Figure}
  {\par\medskip\noindent\minipage{\linewidth}}
  {\endminipage\par\medskip}
```

I am using it because I don't know why `figure*` does not work here...

So now, when I want to include a figure in my report I am doing this:

```
\begin{Figure}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[scale=0.4]{pictures/tab_corr.png}
    \captionof{figure}{}
    \label{fig:corrplot}
\end{Figure}
```

However, for some pictures, it leaves a huge blank space between the text and the figure and I don't know how to remove it.

Thanks for answering me !

Comment: figure creates a floating environment, but in 2 column mode it is not clear where figures should float too, the same column, the next column or same page, etc. This `Figure` environment is one I have used in the past and it just puts the contents inside a minipage, and so there is no floating behaviour, and sometimes this leads to large whitespace, because unlike a paragraph, a figure cannot be broken or split over the two columns.

Comment: The intention with such an enviornment is that you need to move it by hand in the source to come at a good place with respect to column breaks as multicolumn does not support floating figures.

Comment: You might find the following useful https://texblog.org/2012/07/30/single-column-figuretable-in-a-two-multi-column-environment/

Comment: Another work around might be to allow the text to flow around it using [`wrapfig`](http://mirror.ox.ac.uk/sites/ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/wrapfig/wrapfig-doc.pdf), albeit I haven't doe it myself, the 3rd bullet on page 1 says this is possible.

Comment: Thanks for your answers however I can't find out how to do it ... I'll try something else and let you know about it

Comment: See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/530084/i-want-to-wrap-text-only-above-and-below-a-figure-inside-of-a-column.

Comment: BTW, I suspect the reason multicol does not support floats is that the entire page is formatted as a single column which is then split into columns at the end of the page.  It could theoretically support top  floats in the first column and bottom floats in the last column, but that would look weird.