# How to insert an image with multicols

Tags: floats, miktex, texstudio

I have a `\begin{multicols}{2}` document with these conditions.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage[lmargin=2cm, rmargin=2cm, top=1.5cm, bottom=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[british,UKenglish,USenglish,english,american]{babel}
```

However I can't find a way of inserting an image inside one of the columns, like in the image.

[image]

So far I've tried these two options:

```
        \begin{figure}
            %  \centering
            \includegraphics[width=.30\linewidth]{images/GRIN1.png}
            \caption{Subunidad de NMDA codificada por GRIN1. Imagen obtenida con \textit{Chimera}.}
            \label{fig: GRIN1}
        \end{figure}
```

```
        \bigskip
        \noindent  
        \begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
            \centering
            \includegraphics[width=.30\linewidth]{images/GRIN1.png}
            \captionof{Subunidad de NMDA codificada por GRIN1. Imagen obtenida con \textit{Chimera}.}{Figure caption}
            \label{fig:cc}
        \end{minipage}
```

But the first one seems to be ignore by latex, and the second one gives me different errors.

Comment: In `multicols` environment you can not insert floats.

Comment: Which error messages do you get using your second minipage-bades attempt?

Comment: See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/530084/i-want-to-wrap-text-only-above-and-below-a-figure-inside-of-a-column

Answer (score 4):

How about this?

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-4]
\begin{figure}[!h]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{a.png}
\end{figure}
\lipsum[1-1]
\end{document}
```

[image]