# I cannot seem to understand why my image is not generating when I compile my latex document

Tags: floats, multicol, includegraphics, report

I am trying to make a lab report and want a few sections/subsections to be in two columns, but when I try changing it to two columns, it doesn't generate my image when I compile it.
I tried using `\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{chapter/introduction/Thermionic.png}` which works fine but I want to use `\begin{figure} \end{figure}` as I need to include a caption and label it. Below is my code for this.

```
\begin{multicols}{2}

When a metal filament is heated in a vacuum by passing a sufficient large current along the filament, electrons are emitted. By applying a positive voltage to an anode nearby, a current will start flowing between the filament (which acts as a cathode) and the anode. This setup is known as the \textbf{thermionic diode}. Figure \ref{fig:thermdiode} shows the schematic of a thermionic diode similar to the one used in the experiment. \cite{labbook}

\begin{figure}[h!]
  {\includegraphics[width = 0.5\textwidth]{chapter/introduction/Thermionic.png}}
    
  \caption{Schematic Diagram of a Thermionic Diode  \cite{labbook}}
  \label{fig:ThermDiode}
\end{figure}

%\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{chapter/introduction/Thermionic.png}
\end{multicols}
```

I can't seem to understand what's wrong with my code. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Welcome. // Please make it a habit to present code we can copy and compile. Please start at \documentclass and end at \end{document}. Please edit your code as needed. Thanks.

Comment: Somewhat related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/530084/i-want-to-wrap-text-only-above-and-below-a-figure-inside-of-a-column

Answer (score 6):

LaTeX's float mechanism is partly disabled in `multicols`. So you can use `\captionof`.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{showframe}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{multicol}
\begin{document}
\begin{multicols}{2}
When a metal filament is heated in a vacuum by passing a sufficient large current along the filament, electrons are emitted. By applying a positive voltage to an anode nearby, a current will start flowing between the filament (which acts as a cathode) and the anode. This setup is known as the \textbf{thermionic diode}. \figurename~\ref{fig:ThermDiode} shows the schematic of a thermionic diode similar to the one used in the experiment.
\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[width = 0.5\textwidth]{example-image}
\captionof{figure}{Schematic Diagram of a Thermionic Diode}
\label{fig:ThermDiode}
\end{minipage}
\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

[image]