Why twocolumn allows floats but not multicols?
I love the multicols package, but am at a loss of why it does not support floats, when the built-in twocolumns does.
I know there are tricks, like using [H] from the float package, but this disables the float and therefore the text is not automatically balanced above and below the figure. This is impactful when adding new figures, or changing formats, fonts, etc.
I have compiled these two examples to illustrate the advantages and disadvantages of each method:
Using multicols
\documentclass[10pt]{book}
\usepackage[a4paper, portrait, tmargin=2.92cm, bmargin=2.92cm, lmargin=2.54cm, rmargin=1.9cm]{geometry}
\setlength{\columnsep}{0.51cm}

\usepackage{multicol} % muticol support
\usepackage{float} % allows {figure}[H]
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
    
    \par Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent eget nisl in est pellentesque scelerisque. Cras eget fermentum ipsum, lacinia sagittis augue. Nam fermentum diam in leo rutrum, at porta nunc accumsan. Sed ac cursus tortor. Fusce at massa elit. In luctus, magna varius ullamcorper tincidunt, nunc nisi finibus sapien, ut consectetur nisi dui a lacus. Proin commodo condimentum nisi, sit amet eleifend nunc fermentum in. Phasellus venenatis enim in massa hendrerit ullamcorper. Pellentesque non vulputate mauris. Aliquam interdum erat sapien, nec porttitor libero elementum eu. Maecenas in tristique est. Duis ac metus ut dolor commodo rutrum. Maecenas vel porttitor leo. Suspendisse mattis sagittis velit, eget consequat risus facilisis at.   
    \par Duis egestas dui sit amet malesuada faucibus. Etiam ultricies nisl orci, non vulputate velit ornare eu. Vivamus varius risus quis lacus gravida, at imperdiet felis mollis. Praesent eu enim ac libero suscipit maximus sed a odio. Praesent vel risus ac ex congue iaculis vel ut ipsum. Aliquam erat volutpat. Nulla convallis eros ipsum, non convallis turpis facilisis at. Maecenas condimentum tincidunt aliquet. Vestibulum venenatis interdum dui, vel condimentum enim. Cras non turpis eleifend, tempor justo egestas, interdum diam.    
    \par Sed ut suscipit lorem. Mauris ut ultricies lacus. Quisque euismod interdum diam id placerat. Fusce quis mattis nisi. Nullam lobortis felis vitae suscipit consequat. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia curae; Nam metus purus, vulputate ut pharetra dapibus, vehicula eleifend massa. Sed scelerisque augue eros, ac vehicula leo lobortis bibendum.   
    \par Integer non dolor purus. Mauris ac dolor eget enim blandit egestas nec sit amet magna. Etiam id aliquam mi, facilisis luctus ligula. Nunc arcu massa, efficitur ut ligula non, laoreet pharetra dui. Aenean libero eros, blandit id leo elementum, eleifend maximus enim. Donec gravida consectetur ipsum placerat tincidunt. Sed vel mauris ut ipsum porta fringilla. Pellentesque eu dolor ut mauris ullamcorper viverra et ut libero. Vestibulum consequat suscipit nulla. Proin at pulvinar urna, nec blandit nisi. Etiam velit purus, posuere non dui vitae, sollicitudin viverra lectus. Quisque eget tincidunt arcu. Donec ac neque ultrices, tempor dolor condimentum, tempus orci. Cras at molestie purus, congue bibendum erat.

    \begin{multicols}{2}        
    \par Fusce dignissim, lectus ac placerat facilisis, nunc nunc dapibus ligula, quis fermentum neque ex id lacus. Vestibulum at sapien ut leo aliquam cursus. Mauris vel eleifend tellus. Suspendisse id nulla et ipsum aliquet fringilla. Vestibulum quis dolor faucibus, porta turpis at, dignissim odio. Pellentesque ex leo, ultricies eget scelerisque venenatis, pellentesque a tortor. Proin feugiat eu lectus sed malesuada. Donec id convallis enim. Mauris vel vulputate odio, eu gravida odio. Aenean nisl lacus, iaculis vel ligula eget, lacinia imperdiet sem. Integer viverra lorem ipsum, ut viverra mauris lobortis id. Sed est lacus, congue in purus et, lacinia lacinia massa.
    \par Curabitur bibendum imperdiet orci, consectetur semper ante feugiat in. Nulla ac erat nec ante suscipit malesuada. Fusce sapien purus, malesuada nec purus rutrum, convallis laoreet est. Vivamus vehicula volutpat mollis. Maecenas egestas metus sit amet porttitor imperdiet. Duis fringilla bibendum dolor vitae luctus. Aenean placerat libero at orci porttitor lobortis. Suspendisse molestie augue non finibus ornare.

    \begin{figure}[H]
        \includegraphics[width=\columnwidth]{example-image}
    \end{figure}    
    
    \par Ut in sem eget lorem venenatis efficitur et sed nulla. Sed ac ipsum sit amet ipsum viverra iaculis id vel tellus. Vestibulum elementum est et odio consectetur ultricies. Donec libero lacus, finibus sit amet nunc sed, eleifend maximus neque. Vestibulum accumsan, justo venenatis pellentesque mattis, nunc mi tincidunt felis, eu ornare tellus augue id libero. Aliquam erat volutpat. Curabitur ut libero quis enim placerat auctor. Nam egestas posuere augue, vitae sollicitudin nibh vulputate ut. Nulla egestas ante lacus, a scelerisque nisi tristique vitae. Aliquam erat volutpat. Integer auctor metus id commodo fringilla.       
    \par Phasellus dignissim nisi et urna fringilla, quis molestie enim egestas. Etiam elit nulla, convallis ut malesuada eu, tincidunt quis odio. Aenean sodales consequat faucibus. Ut mattis tristique quam, eu pellentesque ligula pulvinar at. Donec quis diam consectetur enim viverra dictum tristique eget augue. Pellentesque fermentum consequat felis. Aenean porttitor metus non libero ullamcorper rhoncus. Curabitur sed tincidunt elit. Proin eget porta ante, vel laoreet tellus. Sed ullamcorper quam hendrerit convallis consequat. Pellentesque mollis, sapien vel efficitur pulvinar, tellus est pellentesque nulla, sit amet vulputate lectus risus eu neque. Donec blandit tincidunt eros, at varius nibh ornare in. Vivamus ac interdum nisi. Sed cursus commodo accumsan. Integer accumsan a dui sit amet vehicula. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia curae; Integer placerat felis enim, sed feugiat mauris scelerisque at. Vestibulum sed congue tellus, nec suscipit justo. In in metus at ipsum ultricies euismod non sit amet ipsum. Fusce sed fringilla nisl.
    \end{multicols}

\end{document}

renders as:

Advantages:

Perfect balancing of columns on last page
Can mix perfectly on the same page areas with 1, 2, 3 columns, etc.
Styling that is declared in preamble applies in all column sections

Disadvantages:

Does not support floats: in this example, there is a big white space left due to the fact the [H] forces the image to appear between the 2 \par. Of course one could put the [H] exactly after the letter where it should cut, but this defeats the purpose of automation and fails if text before the figure is modified.

Using twocolumns
\documentclass[10pt, twocolumn]{book}
\usepackage[a4paper, portrait, tmargin=2.92cm, bmargin=2.92cm, lmargin=2.54cm, rmargin=1.9cm]{geometry}
\setlength{\columnsep}{0.51cm}

\usepackage{multicol} % muticol support
\usepackage{float} % allows {figure}[H]
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
    
    \twocolumn[
    \par Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent eget nisl in est pellentesque scelerisque. Cras eget fermentum ipsum, lacinia sagittis augue. Nam fermentum diam in leo rutrum, at porta nunc accumsan. Sed ac cursus tortor. Fusce at massa elit. In luctus, magna varius ullamcorper tincidunt, nunc nisi finibus sapien, ut consectetur nisi dui a lacus. Proin commodo condimentum nisi, sit amet eleifend nunc fermentum in. Phasellus venenatis enim in massa hendrerit ullamcorper. Pellentesque non vulputate mauris. Aliquam interdum erat sapien, nec porttitor libero elementum eu. Maecenas in tristique est. Duis ac metus ut dolor commodo rutrum. Maecenas vel porttitor leo. Suspendisse mattis sagittis velit, eget consequat risus facilisis at.   
    \par Duis egestas dui sit amet malesuada faucibus. Etiam ultricies nisl orci, non vulputate velit ornare eu. Vivamus varius risus quis lacus gravida, at imperdiet felis mollis. Praesent eu enim ac libero suscipit maximus sed a odio. Praesent vel risus ac ex congue iaculis vel ut ipsum. Aliquam erat volutpat. Nulla convallis eros ipsum, non convallis turpis facilisis at. Maecenas condimentum tincidunt aliquet. Vestibulum venenatis interdum dui, vel condimentum enim. Cras non turpis eleifend, tempor justo egestas, interdum diam.    
    \par Sed ut suscipit lorem. Mauris ut ultricies lacus. Quisque euismod interdum diam id placerat. Fusce quis mattis nisi. Nullam lobortis felis vitae suscipit consequat. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia curae; Nam metus purus, vulputate ut pharetra dapibus, vehicula eleifend massa. Sed scelerisque augue eros, ac vehicula leo lobortis bibendum.   
    \par Integer non dolor purus. Mauris ac dolor eget enim blandit egestas nec sit amet magna. Etiam id aliquam mi, facilisis luctus ligula. Nunc arcu massa, efficitur ut ligula non, laoreet pharetra dui. Aenean libero eros, blandit id leo elementum, eleifend maximus enim. Donec gravida consectetur ipsum placerat tincidunt. Sed vel mauris ut ipsum porta fringilla. Pellentesque eu dolor ut mauris ullamcorper viverra et ut libero. Vestibulum consequat suscipit nulla. Proin at pulvinar urna, nec blandit nisi. Etiam velit purus, posuere non dui vitae, sollicitudin viverra lectus. Quisque eget tincidunt arcu. Donec ac neque ultrices, tempor dolor condimentum, tempus orci. Cras at molestie purus, congue bibendum erat.
    ]

    \par Fusce dignissim, lectus ac placerat facilisis, nunc nunc dapibus ligula, quis fermentum neque ex id lacus. Vestibulum at sapien ut leo aliquam cursus. Mauris vel eleifend tellus. Suspendisse id nulla et ipsum aliquet fringilla. Vestibulum quis dolor faucibus, porta turpis at, dignissim odio. Pellentesque ex leo, ultricies eget scelerisque venenatis, pellentesque a tortor. Proin feugiat eu lectus sed malesuada. Donec id convallis enim. Mauris vel vulputate odio, eu gravida odio. Aenean nisl lacus, iaculis vel ligula eget, lacinia imperdiet sem. Integer viverra lorem ipsum, ut viverra mauris lobortis id. Sed est lacus, congue in purus et, lacinia lacinia massa.        
    \par Curabitur bibendum imperdiet orci, consectetur semper ante feugiat in. Nulla ac erat nec ante suscipit malesuada. Fusce sapien purus, malesuada nec purus rutrum, convallis laoreet est. Vivamus vehicula volutpat mollis. Maecenas egestas metus sit amet porttitor imperdiet. Duis fringilla bibendum dolor vitae luctus. Aenean placerat libero at orci porttitor lobortis. Suspendisse molestie augue non finibus ornare.

    \begin{figure}[!b]
        \includegraphics[width=\columnwidth]{example-image}
    \end{figure}    
    
    \par Ut in sem eget lorem venenatis efficitur et sed nulla. Sed ac ipsum sit amet ipsum viverra iaculis id vel tellus. Vestibulum elementum est et odio consectetur ultricies. Donec libero lacus, finibus sit amet nunc sed, eleifend maximus neque. Vestibulum accumsan, justo venenatis pellentesque mattis, nunc mi tincidunt felis, eu ornare tellus augue id libero. Aliquam erat volutpat. Curabitur ut libero quis enim placerat auctor. Nam egestas posuere augue, vitae sollicitudin nibh vulputate ut. Nulla egestas ante lacus, a scelerisque nisi tristique vitae. Aliquam erat volutpat. Integer auctor metus id commodo fringilla.       
    \par Phasellus dignissim nisi et urna fringilla, quis molestie enim egestas. Etiam elit nulla, convallis ut malesuada eu, tincidunt quis odio. Aenean sodales consequat faucibus. Ut mattis tristique quam, eu pellentesque ligula pulvinar at. Donec quis diam consectetur enim viverra dictum tristique eget augue. Pellentesque fermentum consequat felis. Aenean porttitor metus non libero ullamcorper rhoncus. Curabitur sed tincidunt elit. Proin eget porta ante, vel laoreet tellus. Sed ullamcorper quam hendrerit convallis consequat. Pellentesque mollis, sapien vel efficitur pulvinar, tellus est pellentesque nulla, sit amet vulputate lectus risus eu neque. Donec blandit tincidunt eros, at varius nibh ornare in. Vivamus ac interdum nisi. Sed cursus commodo accumsan. Integer accumsan a dui sit amet vehicula. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia curae; Integer placerat felis enim, sed feugiat mauris scelerisque at. Vestibulum sed congue tellus, nec suscipit justo. In in metus at ipsum ultricies euismod non sit amet ipsum. Fusce sed fringilla nisl.

\end{document}

renders as:

Advantages:

Float is supported:

paragraph is automatically broken as required by image size
adding text or another figure before this one, resizing paper, or margins, automatically readjust column break while figure is left at the requested position (i.e. here the bottom of the column)



Disadvantages:

No balancing of columns on last page
Can have 1 column followed by 2 columns without a page break, but need to use the \twocolumn[prelim] square brackets, which is a hack not really designed for it
Cannot have the reverse: a 2 column followed by a 1 column area without break
Styling declared in preamble is not repeated in the [prelim] 1-column part, need to rewrite commands inside the square brackets to match the outside). Here the spacing between the [prelim] and the following 2-columns lacks vertical space.

Could you please let me know if I am correct in my assessment? Or have I missed something? Are there packages or tricks that I do not know about, which provide the best of both worlds?

the multicol documentation says why floats are not supported: "This is dictated by lack of time. To implement floats one has to reimplement the whole LaTeX output routine."

@UlrikeFischer: yes, I read that. How come however that the built-in twocolumn does implement floats?

Because the build-in twocolumn is part of the LaTeX output routine and The LaTeX Team spend the time needed to implement it. You should be happy and thankful.

I am happy and thankful, but that is a bit out of scope of this discussion... The thing is: is it a technical impossibility to do this in multicols, or is it just a lack of resources or time? Because this would help know if it is worth spending efforts on trying to get this feature.

The multicol code contains a \set@floatcmds and the code documentation says about it This is
the hook for the experts who like to implement a full float mechanism for the \mc{} environment. The |@| in the name should signal that this might not be easy. .  For twocolumn it is much easier, as it starts with a \clearpage and so flushes out all pending floats (and again when going back to \onecolumn, but a multicol can't do that. See https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/39020/2388 for a description of the float algorithm.

@UlrikeFischer: very detailed, thanks a lot!

The standard latex two column mode is hardly different from one column, it just has a narrower text block and puts two text blocks at a time on the same physical page. the multicolmn version is almost completely different you can change columns mid-page and balancing means that adding any float would potentially require the columns to be re-balanced and some algorithm that converged in real time would have to be invented.

Somewhat related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/530084/i-want-to-wrap-text-only-above-and-below-a-figure-inside-of-a-column

note that two column mode doesn't support all aspects of floats available in single column mode. you can't have floats at the bottom, for example.

Also, the balance package will balance twocolumn text.

Thanks all for your comments. Yes, the balance package, as well as the cuted package, may help alleviate some of the limitations of the twocolumn mode. Losing floats in multicols is a big deal for me, despite the high quality of the package.

@cfr: look at my twocolumn example, this is exactly what I do and it works fine.

I meant that you can't have two-column floats at the bottom; you can have one-column floats at the bottom in two-column mode. (actually, you can have them but not out-of-the-box.)

@JohnKormylo: this is an amazing feature. Of course, in practice, with quite a lot of text and images, this makes the process tedious, but this may be a proof it is possible to achieve something. I saw also a similar attempt and code prototype in this thread: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/57732/placing-figures-inside-a-two-column-document

@cfr: I see, you mean one float at the bottom of each column? Or one float that span over the two columns?

RE. one column followed by two column, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/477188/removing-the-space-in-the-page-before-appendix.

@EricFernandez you can't have one which spans both columns at the bottom the way you can at the top. there are also some restrictions on the placement of spanning floats at the top. the placement isn't as flexible as in single column mode.

There are several reasons why multicols does not support floats.  Floats are formatted when they are created, which depends on the column width.  That is why \twocolumn and \onecolumn issue an automatic \clearpage to enpty the float queue with the old column width.  So the first thing multicols would have to do is empty the float queue without a \clearpage.
Multicols puts the entire page into one column, then breaks the column into two or more pieces.  Normally floats are added to a column immediately (if they fit), or at least \@pagegoal is reduced by the size of the float to reduce the space for text. It may not be possible to fit a bunch of floats of various sizes into columns (in the correct order) at the end of the page.  At best you could put all the floats that didn't fit back into the queue and leave a big gap at the bottom of the page.
