Undesired blank space above and bellow image
Im working on a poster, but the spacing is giving me a bunch of problems. Right now i have a graph on the introduction section that is occupyying a bunch of pace; not because it is too big, the size of the image is fine, but because for some reason there is a bunch of dead space both abov and bellow the image. Please help me fix this. coded:
\documentclass{sciposter}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{epsfig}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{graphicx,url}
\usepackage[spanish, english]{babel}   
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{multirow}
\newtheorem{Def}{Definition}

\title{Jaibo - A1 6 Axis cinema robot}
\author{Varuna Cano Maillefert (A01659752 \\ Israel Macías (Advisor), R.E. Gutiérrez-Carvajal (Advisor)}
\institute 
{School of Engineering and Science, Instituto Tecnológico de Monterrey CCM\\
Prol. Canal de Miramontes, Coapa}
\email{VarunaCanoMaillefert@gmail.mx}

\rightlogo[1]{expo ingenierias}
\leftlogo[1]{tec}

\begin{document}
\conference{{\bf Expo Ingeniería 2024}, Tecnológico de Monterrey, Campus Ciudad de México}

\maketitle
\hrule\vspace{0.2cm} 
\vspace{1cm} 

%Abstract------------------------------------------------

\noindent
\begin{minipage}[t]{\textwidth} 
    \textbf{\LARGE Abstract} \vspace{0.5cm} \\
    \textbf{The project involves} the development of a six-degree-of-freedom robotic arm designed for cinema and video applications, featuring a horizontal reach of one meter and a payload capacity of up to 2.5 kilograms. The use of an amateur or semi-professional camera and its lens is permitted. \textbf{The project was divided into two phases: the first phase focuses on state-of-the-art research, selection of key components, actuator design, and mechanical design. The second phase encompasses the implementation of kinematics, communication, and assembly.} 
    During the current semester, the first phase was completed. Initially, a feasibility analysis was conducted based on the state-of-the-art in robotic arms, the film industry, and the application of robotics within it. This analysis defined key parameters for the robot, such as reach, speed, payload capacity, weight, and cost. Based on these parameters, \textbf{BLDC motors, Moteurs R4.1 controllers, and a cycloidal gear reduction system were selected, and the CAD design of the robotic arm was initiated.}
\end{minipage}

\vspace{1cm} 
\hrule\vspace{0.5cm} 

\begin{multicols}{3}

%%% Introduction-----------------------------------------
\section{Introduction}
\PARstart{I}n the film and television industry, specialized tools such as dollies, stabilizers, and cranes are commonly used for controlled and specific camera movements. While these devices enable precise and repeatable motions, they offer limited degrees of freedom, restricting their ability to perform more complex shots. Achieving such shots typically requires robotic arms or CGI, both of which involve high costs, access to specialized equipment, and a significant learning curve. 

Meanwhile, the video production industry is experiencing rapid growth. With widespread internet access, the barriers to entry for video creation has significantly decreased; as evidenced by the over 500 hours of content uploaded daily to YouTube. Within this context, the Jaibo A1 project was developed: a robotic arm for cinematography, designed to offer competitive speeds and reach compared to professional equipment, but at a fraction of the cost. Although the system is designed for a lower payload, it aims to be an accessible tool in a country that, despite lacking Hollywood-level budgets, produces approximately 200 films annually, of which almost half are debut films. 

\begin{figure}[h]
%\vspace{-1cm}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth, keepaspectratio]{YT accounts.png}
\caption{Graph showing number of YouTube accounts per year 2010 to 2023}
%\vspace{-3cm}
\end{figure}
%\vspace{-3.5cm}

%Metodología}--------------------------------------------
\section{Metodology}
A preliminary investigation was conducted to assess the economic and commercial viability of the project, for this, the state of the art in collaborative and cinematographic robots was studied. This analysis facilitated key decisions regarding components, requirements, and techniques for the design and construction of the Jaibo A1 project.

The selected motor was a three-phase BLDC outrunner model manufactured by T Motors, chosen because of its energy efficiency, low maintenance, silent operation, and precise control, and its dimensions. The Field-Oriented Control (FOC) technique was adopted due to its high efficiency, constant torque under dynamic loads, low noise, and high torque output. For the feedback, an integrated encoder was selected. The Moteus R4 controller was chosen because of its compatibility with other components; it includes the encoder on its back. Concurrently, the MotorWare program by Texas Instruments was used for rapid motor setup and component testing. This software includes fifteen labs to facilitate familiarization with Code Composer Studio and FOC.

\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.8\textwidth, keepaspectratio]{RO60.jpg}
\caption{T-motors Ro60 BLDC motor}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.6\textwidth, keepaspectratio]{Moteus-R4.png}
\caption{MJ-Bots Moteus r4.11}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.6\textwidth, keepaspectratio]{cycloidal drive.png}
\caption{Reduction geometry - cycloidal gear box prototype}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.8} % Increase row height by 50%
\begin{tabular}{ |p{6.2cm}||p{6cm}|p{4.5cm}|p{3.5cm}|  }
 \hline
 \multicolumn{4}{|c|}{\LARGE Bill of materials} \\
 \hline
 \large Component & \large Model & \large Quantity & \large Price \\
 \hline
 Driver/Encoder   & Moteus r4.11 & 6 & 79 usd \\
 Motors & RO60 & 6 & 75 usd \\
 Small bearings & 686-2RS & 90 &  16 mxn\\
 Big bearings & 6807-2RS & 18 &  23 mxn\\
 \hline
\end{tabular}
\caption{Bill of matials with quantities}
\end{figure}

The mechanical design of the actuators was also defined following the research into the state of the art. The systems considered where: planetary gears, harmonic drives, capstan drives, and cycloidal drives. The first options were discarded due to their design complexity, and mechanical backlash. The capstan drive on the other hand, was eliminated due to rotational limitations. Ultimately opting for cycloidal gears, torque calculations were performed for all six joints of the arm, considering motor characteristics and a twenty percent tolerance margin. For the three upper joints, a ten to one reduction was deemed sufficient, while for the lower 3 joints, two of the same actuators would be connected in series, making a one hundred to one reduction. The CAD design of the actuators was created in Fusion 360, utilizing a specialized cycloidal gear add-on.

\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.8\textwidth, keepaspectratio]{exploded view.png}
\caption{Final Cycloidal actuator design}
\end{figure}

%Resultados--------------------------------------------------
\section{Resultados}
The progress made during this semester includes the selection of key components, the CAD design of the actuators, the preliminary validation of control and assembly strategies  for the Jaibo A1. A preliminary design of the arm has also been completed in order to calculate the robot's workspace.

\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.8\textwidth, keepaspectratio]{arm bot.png}
\caption{Robot simulation \& workspace}
\end{figure}

%Conclusión--------------------------------------------------
\section{Conclusión}
The rapid growth of digital video platforms and the normalization of this format as a medium of expression highlight the need for accessible tools for Mexican creatives. While similar equipment exists in the industry, their high cost and complexity make them inaccessible to most. The Jaibo A1 aims to provide a compact, affordable solution capable of supporting a semi-professional or amateur camera, serving as a tribute to the creativity of those who transform ideas into audiovisual realities.

%Agradecimientos---------------------------------------------
\section{Agradecimientos}
Thanks are extended to Israel Macías for his help, advice, and the tools provided for the execution of this project. Gratitude is also given to Ricardo for his support and guidance during the presentation, and to Israel Cayetano for his advice and encouragement.


%Referencias
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\begin{thebibliography}{1}

\bibitem{Flusser:Suk:93}
J.~Flusser and T.~Suk.
\newblock Pattern recognition by affine moment invariants.
\newblock {\em Pattern Recognition}, 26:167--174, 1993.

\bibitem{Hu:62}
M.~K. Hu.
\newblock Visual pattern recognition by moment invariants.
\newblock {\em IRE Transactions on Information Theory}, IT-8:179--187, 1962.

\bibitem{maragos89:_patter}
P.~Maragos.
\newblock Pattern spectrum and multiscale shape representation.
\newblock {\em IEEE Trans. Patt. Anal. Mach. Intell.}, 11:701--715, 1989.

\end{thebibliography}

\end{multicols}
\end{document}



you are using [H] which by design introduces ugly white space with the intention that you manually move the words and image in the source to avoid bad page breaks. Its only purpose is to disable the usual automatic placement of figures,

You have not provided a usable example, put presumably figure 2 does not fit in column 1 and you have prevented it floating so it has to break the column before that figure. So if keeping [H] you need to move more words earlier so they may be typeset in column 1

unrelated but no document written after 1994 should be using epsfig package which is a legacy wrapper for documents written using a package of that name in the 1980s.

thanks for the advice. The epsfig package came with the template i used, but thanks for the clarification. As for the [H], i also tried with [h] and [t] but no chages seem to occure

Note that multicols does not support floats.  It is possible to fake it, but not easy (https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/530084/i-want-to-wrap-text-only-above-and-below-a-figure-inside-of-a-column/530129?r=SearchResults&s=24%7C22.0372#530129).

I see what you mean about figure 2 now. thanks, that actually fixed it

What I would do is create a single column document with the desired width and height, save the pdf, then copy it into multicols one page at a time.

Remove the % before the \vspace command, also add \vspace{-...cm} before and after other images, and adjust accordingly.
I assume you want your code to display in one page. Take a look at this.
\documentclass{sciposter}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{epsfig}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{graphicx,url}
\usepackage[spanish, english]{babel}   
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{multirow}
\newtheorem{Def}{Definition}

\title{Jaibo - A1 6 Axis cinema robot}
\author{Varuna Cano Maillefert (A01659752 \\ Israel Macías (Advisor), R.E. Gutiérrez-Carvajal (Advisor)}
\institute 
{School of Engineering and Science, Instituto Tecnológico de Monterrey CCM\\
Prol. Canal de Miramontes, Coapa}
\email{VarunaCanoMaillefert@gmail.mx}

\rightlogo[1]{expo ingenierias}
\leftlogo[1]{tec}

\begin{document}
\conference{{\bf Expo Ingeniería 2024}, Tecnológico de Monterrey, Campus Ciudad de México}

\maketitle
\hrule\vspace{0.2cm} 
\vspace{1cm} 

%Abstract------------------------------------------------

\noindent
\begin{minipage}[t]{\textwidth} 
    \textbf{\LARGE Abstract} \vspace{0.5cm} \\
    \textbf{The project involves} the development of a six-degree-of-freedom robotic arm designed for cinema and video applications, featuring a horizontal reach of one meter and a payload capacity of up to 2.5 kilograms. The use of an amateur or semi-professional camera and its lens is permitted. \textbf{The project was divided into two phases: the first phase focuses on state-of-the-art research, selection of key components, actuator design, and mechanical design. The second phase encompasses the implementation of kinematics, communication, and assembly.} 
    During the current semester, the first phase was completed. Initially, a feasibility analysis was conducted based on the state-of-the-art in robotic arms, the film industry, and the application of robotics within it. This analysis defined key parameters for the robot, such as reach, speed, payload capacity, weight, and cost. Based on these parameters, \textbf{BLDC motors, Moteurs R4.1 controllers, and a cycloidal gear reduction system were selected, and the CAD design of the robotic arm was initiated.}
\end{minipage}

\vspace{1cm} 
\hrule\vspace{0.5cm} 

\begin{multicols}{3}

%%% Introduction-----------------------------------------
\section{Introduction}
\PARstart{I}n the film and television industry, specialized tools such as dollies, stabilizers, and cranes are commonly used for controlled and specific camera movements. While these devices enable precise and repeatable motions, they offer limited degrees of freedom, restricting their ability to perform more complex shots. Achieving such shots typically requires robotic arms or CGI, both of which involve high costs, access to specialized equipment, and a significant learning curve. 

Meanwhile, the video production industry is experiencing rapid growth. With widespread internet access, the barriers to entry for video creation has significantly decreased; as evidenced by the over 500 hours of content uploaded daily to YouTube. Within this context, the Jaibo A1 project was developed: a robotic arm for cinematography, designed to offer competitive speeds and reach compared to professional equipment, but at a fraction of the cost. Although the system is designed for a lower payload, it aims to be an accessible tool in a country that, despite lacking Hollywood-level budgets, produces approximately 200 films annually, of which almost half are debut films. 
\vspace{-1cm}
\begin{figure}[h]
%\vspace{-1cm}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth, keepaspectratio]{YT accounts.png}
\caption{Graph showing number of YouTube accounts per year 2010 to 2023}
\end{figure}
%Metodología}--------------------------------------------
\section{Metodology}
A preliminary investigation was conducted to assess the economic and commercial viability of the project, for this, the state of the art in collaborative and cinematographic robots was studied. This analysis facilitated key decisions regarding components, requirements, and techniques for the design and construction of the Jaibo A1 project.

The selected motor was a three-phase BLDC outrunner model manufactured by T Motors, chosen because of its energy efficiency, low maintenance, silent operation, and precise control, and its dimensions. The Field-Oriented Control (FOC) technique was adopted due to its high efficiency, constant torque under dynamic loads, low noise, and high torque output. For the feedback, an integrated encoder was selected. The Moteus R4 controller was chosen because of its compatibility with other components; it includes the encoder on its back. Concurrently, the MotorWare program by Texas Instruments was used for rapid motor setup and component testing. This software includes fifteen labs to facilitate familiarization with Code Composer Studio and FOC.

\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.8\textwidth, keepaspectratio]{RO60.jpg}
\caption{T-motors Ro60 BLDC motor}
\end{figure}
\vspace{-2cm}

\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.6\textwidth, keepaspectratio]{Moteus-R4.png}
\caption{MJ-Bots Moteus r4.11}
\end{figure}
\vspace{-2cm}

\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.6\textwidth, keepaspectratio]{cycloidal drive.png}
\caption{Reduction geometry - cycloidal gear box prototype}
\end{figure}
\vspace{-1cm}

\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.8} % Increase row height by 50%
\begin{tabular}{ |p{6.2cm}||p{6cm}|p{4.5cm}|p{3.5cm}|  }
 \hline
 \multicolumn{4}{|c|}{\LARGE Bill of materials} \\
 \hline
 \large Component & \large Model & \large Quantity & \large Price \\
 \hline
 Driver/Encoder   & Moteus r4.11 & 6 & 79 usd \\
 Motors & RO60 & 6 & 75 usd \\
 Small bearings & 686-2RS & 90 &  16 mxn\\
 Big bearings & 6807-2RS & 18 &  23 mxn\\
 \hline
\end{tabular}
\caption{Bill of matials with quantities}
\end{figure}
\vspace{-1cm}
The mechanical design of the actuators was also defined following the research into the state of the art. The systems considered where: planetary gears, harmonic drives, capstan drives, and cycloidal drives. The first options were discarded due to their design complexity, and mechanical backlash. The capstan drive on the other hand, was eliminated due to rotational limitations. Ultimately opting for cycloidal gears, torque calculations were performed for all six joints of the arm, considering motor characteristics and a twenty percent tolerance margin. For the three upper joints, a ten to one reduction was deemed sufficient, while for the lower 3 joints, two of the same actuators would be connected in series, making a one hundred to one reduction. The CAD design of the actuators was created in Fusion 360, utilizing a specialized cycloidal gear add-on.

\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.8\textwidth, keepaspectratio]{exploded view.png}
\caption{Final Cycloidal actuator design}
\end{figure}

%Resultados--------------------------------------------------
\section{Resultados}
The progress made during this semester includes the selection of key components, the CAD design of the actuators, the preliminary validation of control and assembly strategies  for the Jaibo A1. A preliminary design of the arm has also been completed in order to calculate the robot's workspace.

\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.8\textwidth, keepaspectratio]{arm bot.png}
\caption{Robot simulation \& workspace}
\end{figure}
\vspace{-3cm}

%Conclusión--------------------------------------------------
\section{Conclusión}
The rapid growth of digital video platforms and the normalization of this format as a medium of expression highlight the need for accessible tools for Mexican creatives. While similar equipment exists in the industry, their high cost and complexity make them inaccessible to most. The Jaibo A1 aims to provide a compact, affordable solution capable of supporting a semi-professional or amateur camera, serving as a tribute to the creativity of those who transform ideas into audiovisual realities.

%Agradecimientos---------------------------------------------
\section{Agradecimientos}
Thanks are extended to Israel Macías for his help, advice, and the tools provided for the execution of this project. Gratitude is also given to Ricardo for his support and guidance during the presentation, and to Israel Cayetano for his advice and encouragement.


%Referencias
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\begin{thebibliography}{1}

\bibitem{Flusser:Suk:93}
J.~Flusser and T.~Suk.
\newblock Pattern recognition by affine moment invariants.
\newblock {\em Pattern Recognition}, 26:167--174, 1993.

\bibitem{Hu:62}
M.~K. Hu.
\newblock Visual pattern recognition by moment invariants.
\newblock {\em IRE Transactions on Information Theory}, IT-8:179--187, 1962.

\bibitem{maragos89:_patter}
P.~Maragos.
\newblock Pattern spectrum and multiscale shape representation.
\newblock {\em IEEE Trans. Patt. Anal. Mach. Intell.}, 11:701--715, 1989.

\end{thebibliography}

\end{multicols}
\end{document}

