How Can I add to every new column on a multicol environment the current section name?
Thank you for reading.
What I need to do is something sim ilar to this:

I am using multicols package but I can't find how to do what I need. I need the section name on every new column on the document. But I need it automatically because it is a long document.
Thank you.

EDIT:
Thank you very much, my respect.
I am adding more information as was requested.
My work is a cross reference catalog, so I have to list a lot of codes of competitor brands and its match to my brand. There are several brands I need to show and list. The trouble is that when a brand has a lot of codes to match several columns are created but the reader can get lost because there is missing a guide or title to know on what brand is about.
Here is a real pic of my work, and the problem I am facing:

As you can notice, I need to add/repeat on every column the brand name, also could be great to add "Brand name - cont."
About the code, it is very simple, it is just a lot of subsections and lines.
\begin{multicols*}{3}
\subsection*{ACDELCO}
\textbf{156072390}\dotfill \textbf{\hyperlink{W-2391}{ W-2391}}

\textbf{96628890}\dotfill \textbf{\hyperlink{WA-10115}{ WA-10115}}

\textbf{A1019C}\dotfill \textbf{\hyperlink{WCA-7454}{ WCA-7454}}

\textbf{A101C}\dotfill \textbf{\hyperlink{WCA-258 SY}{ WCA-258 SY}}

\textbf{A1030C}\dotfill \textbf{\hyperlink{WCA-3280}{ WCA-3280}}

\textbf{A1033C}\dotfill \textbf{\hyperlink{WCA-7242}{ WCA-7242}}
.
.
.
\subsection*{ZX AUTO}
\textbf{1109020-0100}\dotfill \textbf{\hyperlink{WA-3618}{ WA-3618}}
\end{multicols*}

Those link go to another part of my document. The .TEX file is generated from a DB using a python script so the .TEX file is very long.
My work was inspired on some catalog I have seen before like:

As you can see my inspiration work is using a software similar to LaTex. I don't know what can be.
Final disclaimer: I have shown some commercial brands in my question, those brand are of their owner, I am not related to these brand. I do not pretend to represent any of them, they have all right and I present them as a reference only.
Thank you again.

Welcome to TeX SE. Could you add a minimal, but compilable, code of what you tried? It will help us to help you.

Multicols does the entire page as one column, then splits it into 3 equal parts.  There is no way to find the tops automatically.  See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/530084/i-want-to-wrap-text-only-above-and-below-a-figure-inside-of-a-column

You should consider paracol package instead of multicols. I think it does what you need. multicols is for typesetting multi-column documents where you don't care how columns are arranged, while paracol is for placing specific content to dedicated columns and you control which content goes to dedicated column.

You could probably add something to the header of the page, but without an example it is difficult to say more.

@JohnKormylo it is no longer true that multicol can't do this: with the upcoming LaTeX release in June next year it will support top/first/bottom marks per column. The code is already in the -dev release as distributed so it can be tried out

The example you show indicates that you consider the continuation headings not as part of the text but actually part of the header, given that CYRSLER is one line higher than CLARCOR. Is this the way you wanted it? Because then it is fairly easy to solve in LaTeX with the solution I already outlined.

Dear Frank, thank you again. I edited the photo on MS Paint manually, that is why CHRYSLER looks higher than CLARCOR, it would be great if the continuation could part of the text. But as you said, until that can be possible, I will go with your idea, so thank you very much.

With the upcoming LaTeX release, i.e., in June 2025, LaTeX supports the new mark mechanism throughout, including with the multicol package. That means you can ask for first mark, last mark, but also for top mark (which wasn't possible before) and that on a per column basis.
The code is already in the distributed -dev release so it can be tried out if you use, say:
pdflatex-dev <file>
For example:
\documentclass{article}


\usepackage{fancyhdr,kantlipsum,multicol,calc} 

\pagestyle{fancy}

\fancyhf{}

\fancyhead[L]{%
  \clap{/}%
  \makebox[\headwidth/3][c]{\TopMark[mcol-1]{2e-left}}%
  \clap{/}%
  \makebox[\headwidth/3][c]{\TopMark[mcol-2]{2e-left}}%
  \clap{/}%
  \makebox[\headwidth/3][c]{\TopMark[mcol-3]{2e-left}}%
  \clap{/}%
}
\fancyfoot[L]{%
  \clap{/}%
  \makebox[\headwidth/3][c]{\LastMark[mcol-1]{2e-left}}%
  \clap{/}%
  \makebox[\headwidth/3][c]{\LastMark[mcol-2]{2e-left}}%
  \clap{/}%
  \makebox[\headwidth/3][c]{\LastMark[mcol-3]{2e-left}}%
  \clap{/}%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{multicols}{3}

\section{A}
\kant[1]

\section{B}
\kant[1-2]

\section{C}
\kant[3]

\section{D}
\kant[4]

\section{E}
\kant[5]

\section{F}
\kant[6]

\end{multicols}

\end{document}

gives you pages, where the header shows the top mark of each column and the footer the last mark (using the 2e mark class 2e-left, which is what \section headings use  via \markboth).
(Alternatively, one could use \FirstMarkin the header in which case it would show 1A 2B 3C instead.)
As a result you get this for the first 2 pages:


See texdoc ltmarks-doc for details on the mark mechanism and its commands.
Notes
If the intention is to inject text into the columns rather than into a running header or footer, then this is currently not possible for two reasons:

multicol lacks the ability to do that programatically
There is a deficiency in \@startsection, the command to that is used  to produce most headings (and titletoc that reimplements this), in that it puts the 2e-left mark after the  section break rather than directly before. This way you can't figure out if a section is at the very top of a column or somewhere down inside of it. If placed differently then \TopMark, \FirstMark, and \LastMark together would reflect the true state at the very top of the column: if \TopMark and \FirstMarkare identical, then the section is at the very top, otherwise it isn't (provided that there is any section at all, for which you can test by comparing \TopMark with \LastMark).  With the old mark mechanism it didn't matter because LaTeX wasn't able to handle top marks at all.

Both issues could be resolved, but at the moment each of them is preventing such a solution.

You can use \splitbotmark TeX primitive. I can show you what to to at TeX primitive level:
\def\column{
   \vbox{\hbox{\bf \putmark}\medskip  \setbox1=\vsplit0 to15cm \box1}
}
\def\putmark{\edef\tmp{\splitbotmark}%
   \ifx\tmp\empty \else \xdef\themark{\tmp}\fi
   \themark}
\def\themark{}

% columns accumulated:

\setbox0=\vbox{\hbadness=10000
\hsize=5cm
\medskip{\bf Sec. name}\mark{Sec. name}\par\nobreak\medskip
\lorem[1-4]
\medskip{\bf Other Section}\mark{Other Section}\par\nobreak\medskip
\lorem[5-6]
\medskip{\bf Last section}\mark{Last Section}\par\nobreak\medskip
\lorem[7-9]
}

% columns splitted and printed:

\hbox{\column\kern3mm \column\kern3mm \column}
\vfil\break
\hbox{\column\kern3mm \column\kern3mm \column}

\bye

You can try to process this example by OpTeX (because the \lorem macro is used here). If you replace this macro by analogical dummy text, then you can run this example with classical plain TeX.

the problem with a plain TeX solution as indicated is that it is not really general. Try adding \vfil and \vfilneg to your galley in a way that they cancel each other. Then \vsplit will die with an error and this can happen in real life documents as I found when I tried to design the solution for LaTeX.

@FrankMittelbach I tried putting \vfil\vfilneg but I didn't see that \vsplit die. Maybe, it must be inserted at a special place?

my mistake, I remembered incorrectly. \vfilneg is not a problem, just anything that adds infinite negative glue, e.g., \vss. That can't happen on top-level, but can if you want to also get  marks out of any constructed boxes along the way, which is what you need to do, if you really want to get at all marks.
